# How to save XML node back into XML file with LINQ-to-XML?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I've got an XML file which I use to create objects, change the objects, then **save the objects back** into the XML file.

**What do I have to change in the following code** so that it extracts a node from the XML based on the id, replaces that node with the new one, and saves it back into the XML?

The following gives me **'System.Xml.Linq.XElement' does not contain a constructor that takes '0' arguments'**:

```
//GET ALL SMARTFORMS AS XML
XDocument xmlDoc = null;
try
{
    xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(FullXmlDataStorePathAndFileName);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    HandleXmlFileNotFound(ex);
}

//EXTRACT THE NODE THAT NEEDS TO BE REPLACED
XElement oldElementToOverwrite = xmlDoc.Descendants("smartForm")
    .Where(sf => (int)sf.Element("id") == 2)
    .Select(sf => new XElement());

//CREATE THE NODE THAT WILL REPLACE IT
XElement newElementToSave = new XElement("smartForm",
                              new XElement("id", this.Id),
                              new XElement("idCode", this.IdCode),
                              new XElement("title", this.Title)
                              );

//OVERWRITE OLD WITH NEW
oldElementToOverwrite.ReplaceWith(newElementToSave);

//SAVE XML BACK TO FILE
xmlDoc.Save(FullXmlDataStorePathAndFileName);
```

**XML file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <smartForm>
    <id>1</id>
    <whenCreated>2008-12-31</whenCreated>
    <itemOwner>system</itemOwner>
    <publishStatus>published</publishStatus>
    <correctionOfId>0</correctionOfId>
    <idCode>customerSpecial</idCode>
    <title>Edit Customer Special</title>
    <description>This form has a special setup.</description>
    <labelWidth>200</labelWidth>
  </smartForm>
  <smartForm>
    <id>2</id>
    <whenCreated>2008-12-31</whenCreated>
    <itemOwner>system</itemOwner>
    <publishStatus>published</publishStatus>
    <correctionOfId>0</correctionOfId>
    <idCode>customersMain</idCode>
    <title>Edit Customer</title>
    <description>This form allows you to edit a customer.</description>
    <labelWidth>100</labelWidth>
  </smartForm>
  <smartForm>
    <id>3</id>
    <whenCreated>2008-12-31</whenCreated>
    <itemOwner>system</itemOwner>
    <publishStatus>published</publishStatus>
    <correctionOfId>0</correctionOfId>
    <idCode>customersNameOnly</idCode>
    <title>Edit Customer Name</title>
    <description>This form allows you to edit a customer's name only.</description>
    <labelWidth>100</labelWidth>
  </smartForm>
</root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error has nothing to do with saving, or even with replacement - it has to do with you trying to create an `XElement` without specifying the name. Why are you trying to use `Select` at all? My guess is you just want to use `Single`:

```
XElement oldElementToOverwrite = xmlDoc.Descendants("smartForm")
    .Where(sf => (int)sf.Element("id") == 2)
    .Single();
```

(As Noldorin notes, you can give `Single` a predicate to avoid using `Where` at all. Personally I quite like to split the two operations up, but they'll be semantically equivalent.)

That will return the single element in the sequence, or throw an exception if there are 0 elements or more than one. Alternatives are to use `SingleOrDefault`, `First`, or `FirstOrDefault`:

- `SingleOrDefault` if it's legal to have 0 or 1
- `First` if it's legal to have 1 or more
- `FirstOrDefault` if it's legal to have 0 or more

If you're using an "OrDefault" one, the result will be `null` if there are no matches.

Comment: Single has an overload that takes a predicate, so no need to use `Where`.

Comment: Yup - I had forgotten about that, but I actually find it more readable to use the separate operations anyway :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is simply your use of the `Select` call in the statement assigning `oldElementToOverwrite`. You actually seem to want the `Single` extension method.

```
XElement oldElementToOverwrite = xmlDoc.Descendants("smartForm")
    .Single(sf => (int)sf.Element("id") == 2)
```